# Twilio downloaded but won't import

Tags: python, import, twilio

I downloaded Twilio and I know it's sitting in the right path, but when I tried this

```
import twilio
```

This is the error message that popped up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from six import u
ImportError: No module named six
```

I don't know what this means or what I did wrong. I'm doing the Udacity course on learning python so that is why I need twilio. Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the module [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/1.7.3), which the [Twilio Python library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install) depends upon for supporting both Python versions 2 and 3, is not installed for the Python interpreter you're using. Use pip to install the six library via the command line with `pip install six`.

This module dependency should have been installed during the easy_install and pip process but if you downloaded the library separately the installation process may have skipped retrieving the other dependencies. Note if you're interested in the dependencies that a module has they can be found in the package's [setup.py](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/master/setup.py) file.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Have you checked out our Python helper library [installation instructions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install)?  You can install the library via pip or easy_install or by downloading the source and running the setup script.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I did use easy_install for it and I just re-installed it with pip but the same error message keeps popping up and I have no idea why